# Aligning checkboxes to the right of text

Tags: html, forms

Can someone suggest me how to bring the check box to the right of the letter because  by default it is aligned to the left.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Page title</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>My feedback form</h1>

    <form>

    <ul>

        <li>Name: <input name="name" type="text"></li>

        <li>Email: <input name="email" type="email"></li>

        <li>Password: <input name="Password" type="Password"></li><br>

        <li>Please check all the emoticons that apply to you:</li>

        <ul type="disc">

            <li><input type="checkbox" name="emoticon 1" value="angry"> Angry</li>

            <li><input type="checkbox" name="emoticon 2" value="Sad"> Sad</li>

            <li><input type="checkbox" name="emoticon 3" value="Happy"> Happy</li></li>

            <li><input type="checkbox" name="emoticon 4" value="Ambivalent"> Ambivalent</li></ul>

            <li>How satisfied were you with pur service?</li>

          

           <ul type="disc">

                <li><input type="radio" name="rating 1" value="very satisfied"> Very satisfied</li>

                <li><input type="radio" name="rating 2" value="Satisfied">Satisfied</li>

                <li><input type="radio"

   name="rating 3" value="Didn't care">Didn't care</li>

                <li><input type="radio" 

    name="rating 4" value="Dissatisfied">Dissatisfied</li>

               <li><input type="radio" name="rating 5" value="very dissatisfied">Very dissatisfied</li>

       </ul>

               

<li>Further comments: <textarea name=# "description"></textarea>    

    </ul></form></body></html>
```

This is the code that i typed

Comment: you could use flex on the li with row-reverse

Comment: @Pete you are right

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` cannot be the child of another `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the checkboxes as `inline-block` elements

```html
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>
    <style>
        ul.checklist {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul.checklist li {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        ul.checklist li label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 150px;
        }

        ul.checklist li input[type="checkbox"] {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My feedback form</h1>
    <form>
        <ul class="checklist">
            <li>
                <label for="emoticon1">Angry:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon1" name="emoticon1" value="angry">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="emoticon2">Sad:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon2" name="emoticon2" value="Sad">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="emoticon3">Happy:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon3" name="emoticon3" value="Happy">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="emoticon4">Ambivalent:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon4" name="emoticon4" value="Ambivalent">
            </li>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  using flexbox with `flex-direction: row-reverse` is a effective way to position the checkboxes to the right.

This is update code:

```css
        ul.checklist {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            float:left;
        }

        ul.checklist li {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row-reverse; 
            align-items: center;
            
        }

        ul.checklist li label {
            margin-left: 10px;
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>My feedback form</h1>
    <form>
        <ul class="checklist">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon1" name="emoticon1" value="angry">
                <label for="emoticon1">Angry:</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon2" name="emoticon2" value="Sad">
                <label for="emoticon2">Sad:</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon3" name="emoticon3" value="Happy">
                <label for="emoticon3">Happy:</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="emoticon4" name="emoticon4" value="Ambivalent">
                <label for="emoticon4">Ambivalent:</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```